Troubleshooting RPC Endpoint Issues with Evmos Backend
guys.
I download https://github.com/evmos/evmos/tree/release/v12.x.x and using it.
It is working well.
I can use commands using evmosd service such as
evmosd query bank balances evmos1w0sdrf5ua7guechy776xj59hnqzqqa00mnvkzv
evmosd keys show dev0

But in other side, such as explorer and wallet, I can't connect to the evmos backend.
Wallet Fetch
It might be rpc endpoint problem.
How can I solve it?
I used docker command to reinstall, but still it didn't work well.
